# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This error just appeared randomly. I see that there are lot of answers about it; and I tried looking at the most of the solutions relevant to my case like:

1. deleting gradle file and restarting,
2. using multidex,
3. checked my gradle is the latest one i.e.2.3.3,
4. at some forum it was mentioned that the issue is with realm version I changed that also from 3.0.0 to 3.5.0, 
   but nothing worked.

I observed the mentioned folder in my app folder:

> app->tmp->compileDebugWithJavac

It has one child folder emptySourcePathRef which is empty. Since it is in tmp folder with cleaning this folder is getting deleted and I thought that can be the solution but still nothing.

I still have not solved my problem. Are there any other possible solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self.. I noticed that in realm object class I declared one field as

```
public class MyRealmObject extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
String _id;

RealmList<?> replies;

//    public RealmList<?> getReplies() {
//        return replies;
//    } 
//
//    public void setReplies(RealmList<?> replies) {
//        this.replies = replies;
//    }
```

as removed and added it back and forth I understood that this was the problem. I have posted the issue to know more about it.

https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/242